# How to implement a popup overlay that can be displayed over any other app in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

How can I implement a popup overlay for an app that can be displayed over any other app.

Facebook implemented a very similar feature called Chatheads in its new Facebook Messanger version. I was really surprised to see that this is some how possible. On the image, you see a chathead (dog on the right) over another app.

[image: Facebook Messanger's Chathead over other app]

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question. It might be poorly stated for some people. Rephrase the question so that it focuses more on the screen popup overlays on any app rather than Facebook Messenger itself, attribute it as your example. Screenshot also is nice to give context.

Comment: I hope my question is better now.

Comment: Have a look at the Facebook Messanger comments on Google Play. For some people it doesn't work, it may have something to do with all those TouchWizzes and HTC Senses...

Comment: No no, for me it's working I want to know how I can implement such a behavior for my own app.

Comment: I don't understand why this question gets closed.

Comment: As I said before I believe this question is legitimate. Any of the users that closed this question should really explain why it was closed. There is no communication here.

Comment: http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/ is the answer.

Comment: hello @Jeremy Edwards your link example helpful to me but how i close chaehead ?

Comment: Your Question has been answered check this link out 
.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads

Comment: https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead

Answer (score 7):

Full source code is here: http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics

**Note:** You will need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`

```
public class ChatHeadService extends Service {

  private WindowManager windowManager;
  private ImageView chatHead;

  @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Not used
    return null;
  }

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_head);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
  }
}
```

Comment: @jonney that seems to be an Android 6 issue. You have to explicitly allow this in settings.

Comment: So you need to ask for a SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission. The package installer crashes the moment i ask for the runtime permission. How can i avoid this?

Comment: I got runtime exception says permission need, But I gave permission

Comment: TYPE_PHONE is now deprecated and throws `WindowManager$BadTokenException ... permission denied for window type 2002` on api >=28

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.eatheat.floatingexample&hl=en) is a minimal, simple, and general example of a floating "chathead"-style overlay.

It uses the following code to make things float:

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
chatHead = new ImageView(this);
chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating);
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

The full source source can be found [here](https://github.com/EatHeat/FloatingExample) (under the Apache license).

Comment: TYPE_PHONE is now deprecated and throws `WindowManager$BadTokenException ... permission denied for window type 2002` on api 28>

Answer (score 2):

i know its late to post the answer, i will post it anyway for other people who are seeking the answer

[AndroidFloatingImage](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/AndroidFloatingImage)

Answer (score 2):

There's a library for that if you want Messenger like behavior: [Bubbles](https://github.com/txusballesteros/bubbles-for-android).

If you prefer implement it yourself look at Window Manager as others suggest. You can also take a look at the source code of [Bubbles](https://github.com/txusballesteros/bubbles-for-android) to get inspired.

Answer (score 0):

Every Activity, dialog as well as service is attached with a window. Facebook keeps a service running in background and in the service they fetch window manager object by

`windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);`

Create Layout Params needed while adding your view

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

now add your view to window manager by following method

```
windowManager.addView(yourView, params);
```

Comment: TYPE_PHONE is now deprecated and throws `WindowManager$BadTokenException ... permission denied for window type 2002` on api 28>