# Android drawing on android screens

Tags: android

I am curious and cant find answer for my question, maybe I don't know how should I look for it.
I would like to know how it is possible to draw something on android screens, I mean homescreen, apps screen, camera screen etc, like snowflakes falling from the top of the screen.
Anything that would point me in the right direction would be nice.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You mean full-screen rendering on top of other applications?

Comment: Yes but to let user click icons and interact without problems with the ui

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a popup overlay that can be displayed over any other app in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990049/how-to-implement-a-popup-overlay-that-can-be-displayed-over-any-other-app-in-and)