# How Android apps like Uber, Swiggy, Rapido are able to draw small maps over other apps without any special permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions

[image]

While Ride is in progress or Food is being delivered if we go back or press home then these apps shows these kind of small maps without having draw over other app permission ? How is this possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a popup overlay that can be displayed over any other app in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990049/how-to-implement-a-popup-overlay-that-can-be-displayed-over-any-other-app-in-and)

Comment: Is it picture-in-picture feature? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

Comment: You can name it over lay , picture in picture etc it is just a service with UI

Answer (score 0):

No special permission is required to achieve this. Just picture in picture mode can help you do this.

```
enterPictureInPictureMode(); in onUserLeaveHint()
```