# Android-Overlay/Draw Over Everything

Tags: android, overlay

I am trying to make a android app which can display widgets(button,textbox,etc) over everything(every app or every activity) <strike>much like the facebook chatheads or floating notifications</strike>

so far I am able to draw rectangle over everything except the notifications status bar.

I am using TouchSoftly in this project [github/t0mm13b/TouchSoftly]

so far i am here : http://s21.postimg.org/5fzk796xz/Capture.png

what i want to achieve is http://s10.postimg.org/ptvc3m2eh/Untitled.png

please help me to draw over the notifications bar

what i tried but didnt work for me:

- setting activity to fullscreen
- changing android:gravity values

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Android kitkat (4.4), Google added the [immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html), that allows you to display views over the top and bottom bars.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link for details:

http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

[What APIs in Android is Facebook using to create Chat Heads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)