# Is it possible to create a clickable Toast-like notification?

Tags: android, android-toast

I have a need to show a minimally-intrusive non-blocking notification which is *not* tied to the activity it is shown in (like a [Toast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast)) *and* which is clickable. Does anyone have any idea whether or not this is possible? Unfortunately, it appears that [Toast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast) notifications (custom or otherwise) are not clickable (i.e. setting an [OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener) on its views has no effect). All the alternatives that I'm aware of (i.e. [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog), [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow) and [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton)) seem to show a notification which is tied to the activity it is shown in (i.e. they won't continue showing when the activity finishes). Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads

Comment: You may want to consider using `Snackbar` rather than `Toast` as the former has in-built click/action functionality: https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/

Comment: Are Snackbar instances tied to the Activity in which they're shown? If not, then this is a good solution to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `PopupWindow`, add an `onClickListener` and add a `handler` to auto cancel it after n times (just like the behavior of a `toast`). Something like this:

```
public static void showToast(Activity a, String title, String message) {

    // inflate your xml layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = a.getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
            (ViewGroup) a.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

    // set the custom display
    ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(title);
    ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(message);

    // initialize your popupWindow and use your custom layout as the view
    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

    // set windowType to TYPE_TOAST (requires API 23 above)
    // this will make popupWindow still appear even the activity was closed
    pw.setWindowLayoutType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP, 0, 500);

    // handle popupWindow click event
    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // do anything when popupWindow was clicked
            pw.dismiss(); // dismiss the window
        }
    });

    // dismiss the popup window after 3sec
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            pw.dismiss();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#000"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:elevation="10dp"
              android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove "pw.setWindowLayoutType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);" and can be used under API 23.  Works great on 21.  Thanks!

Comment: new Handler() should be initialized with Looper.getMainLooper() to avoid non prepared looper

Answer (score 1):

You are right, a `Toast` object has no way to be interacted with, but there are many libraries out there that will give you the same look and feel as a toast, but with some interactivity. The one I use is https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts

Comment: Is a `SuperToast` clickable _and_ independent of the activity it was shown in? i.e. will the `SuperToast` continue to appear after the activity it was shown in finishes?

Comment: Thats not possible if you want the message to be clickable. The activity context has been destroyed at that point, any listeners you had set would be destroyed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is in fact a `PopupWindow`which can be seen here "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html".

Toasts have a very specific task, which is to inform the user, without any input from them. So instead of trying to extend the purpose of the Toast, use the PopupWindow which can be interacted with by the user.

Comment: Is a `PopupWindow` independent of the activity it was shown in? i.e. will the `PopupWindow` continue to appear after the activity it was shown in finishes?

Comment: Okay. That's not what I'm after then.

Answer (score 0):

A **'Dialog' type of activity** will probably be your best bet.

In manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ToastLikeActivity"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
             android:label="@string/label"
             ></activity>
```

And timeout the activity within the onCreate():

```
class ToastLikeActivity extends Activity  {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle state)
           // auto-kill activity after X seconds <-------------------------
           Handler handler = new Handler();
           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                        ToastLikeActivity.this.finish(); // kill after X seconds
                   }
           }
    }, VisibleTimeSecs*1000);

}
```

To display the dialog start it as with any other activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ToastLikeActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

And it will show up and automatically go away after X seconds.

Such a popup **will not be tied to the caller activity.** In fact - it will not even require a caller activity. You
can activate it (bad idea, but possible) even from a service.

You can implement basically any kind of sensitive (i.e. accepting user's clicks) interface you want to 
the ToastLikeActivity. Especially: you can **make its exteriors transparent**, giving it a dialog-likke looks.

Comment: The `ToastLikeActivity` will block the activity it is started from. That's not what I'm after.