# Custom toast with "OK" button

Tags: java, android

I tried to add onClick to my custom toast button, but the button doesn't work. Please I need help

```
final Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
View custom_view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_snackbar, null);

Button action = custom_view.findViewById(R.id.sb_action);
action.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View p1) {
        //run code on click
    }

 });

toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
toast.setView(custom_view);
toast.show();
```

Image of my custom toast with button :

[image: Image of my custom toast with button]

Comment: Hi, ToastMessages are not clickable, they provides feedback about something. If you want any user interaction, you should use Snackbars instead of Toasts. Details: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653152/is-it-possible-to-create-a-clickable-toast-like-notification

Comment: This question has already been discussed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653152/is-it-possible-to-create-a-clickable-toast-like-notification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create a clickable Toast-like notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653152/is-it-possible-to-create-a-clickable-toast-like-notification)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you could consider the using a **SnackBar** from the Material design library.

But if you don't want the overhead of the support library, you could use the hack below

```
    try {
            Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.widget.Toast");
            Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("getWindowParams");
            WindowManager.LayoutParams param = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) method.invoke(toast);
            param.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Tested on Android Nougat