# Overlay button over Google Navigation Android

Tags: android, overlay, android-auto

I would like to know if it's possible to overlay a 'return' button over other apps? I'm coding a carPC frontend and when the user clicks the GPS button it launches Google Navigation. What I would like is a semi-transparent button then that floats on top of the GPS software that when clicked swaps easily back to my frontend.

I'm used to coding in vb.net and that has a simple topmost call which sets a form over everything, so it's something like this that I need. I'm guessing it will be an Activity I will need to use with a simple xml layout file with a single ImageView and then add a listener to monitor all screen touches.  Can you add a hook of some sort to achieve this?

Comment: Look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible, you could use a class that extend service that be at top of everything for sure using `windowsManager` and `layaoutParams` , just google Facebook floating chatHead , i would like to provide you with example code but im away from my pc.

Comment: Many thanks for the correct things to look for. I've now got a floating icon :-) I just need the final piece, where I click on it and it brings my app back to the front. I've tried the following but it's a no go..