# Android popup menu widget over each screen like Edge Quick Action

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-appwidget, android-popupwindow

I´d like to make an Android utility application. It should be able to show the transparent popupmenu with some buttons over the homescreen or over some running application (except in fullscreen mode).

I want it to look like that https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.reactivstudios.android.edge.free

Any suggestions how to do it, please? Is it a popupwindow (I think that the popupwindow can be showed only over its parent app)? Is it an activity with transparent background? Is it any type of widget with transparent layout? Or is it a hacked toast? Or is it something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know it's created with Service and adding view to windows manager, you can find example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15980900/341998) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22521311/341998).