# View without Activity - Placement and Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the Code from [JawsWare - Overlay View](http://jawsware.com/code_OverlayView/) to create a View that lays above everything.

This works fine, but I failed to adapt the given layout to my needs.

What I want: Two Phases.
First Phase: A button in the upper left corner that is always there above all other apps.
When this button is pressed, we enter the Second Phase:

The button is replaced by two images which are to be horizontally aligned at a certain distance from the top, again floating above everything else.

I have to admit that I dont really understand Android Layouting, but I've tried fiddling with a *RelativeLayout* and an *ImageView* but it seems buggy.
Additionally, I encountered a very strange behaviour: Even if the Image is only about 200x200 px in the upper left corner, nearly the whole screen is "blocked" by the View (it receives all TouchEvents, even though there shouldt be anything). It seems that if I position the Layout using Margins to float in the middle of the screen, everything to the left and top of the visible button is also receiving touch events and not letting them pass through to the underlying app (even though there is no visible content).

Any ideas to why this happens and how to circumvent that?

Secondly: How can I achieve the two layouts from earlier?

Edit 1: My Layout. (please keep in mind that I just copied this and then did what I thought was right)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:onClick="overlayTextClicked"
android:padding="0dp"
android:id="@+id/overlay_layout_id"
 >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageview_info"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/picture_010512233437384578" 
    android:contentDescription=""/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="info"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Afterwards I am trying to set the RelativeLayouts Gravity to TOP | CENTER_VERTICAL with a Top-Margin of 200px.

Comment: Off the top of my head, your layout is set to "match_parent" in both height and width, but the image is only 200x200 so it's not filling the entire screen even though the View itself is that big.  You need to post your layout.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what's going on here is your `TextView` is filling out the entire screen.

`wrap_content` bounds the size of a View with its content.  `match_parent` fills a view to as big as it can get (i.e., whatever size the container is bound to).

So in this case, your `RelativeLayout` is does not have a max size it's bound to.  Your `TextView` is going to try to get as big as it can get, so it's going to fill the screen.  Likewise, the `RelativeLayout` is going to blow up to that size to wrap around the `TextView`.

Also, `RelativeLayout` doesn't really respond to Gravity well.  That is used in `LinearLayout` and `FrameLayout` containers a lot, but `RelativeLayout` relational rules like "CENTER_IN_PARENT" are going to override whatever Gravity you set (if you set Gravity.RIGHT and "CENTER_IN_PARENT", then one has to win out I guess).

Comment: Wonderful, so this should solve my first problem - but how can I freely position the view on the screen without it "stealing" touch events?
Edit: Yes, I tried it, now that works. But if I use a marginTop on the Layout, the are above it is still not touchable

Comment: You don't want the entire RelativeLayout accepting touch events.  You want one of the much smaller child Views to do it.  Set the "onClick" attribute to your ImageView for example and the click events will only fire on your ImageView (unless you're overriding onTouchEvent on the RelativeLayout and returning "true").

Comment: Once you do that, you can keep the RelativeLayout to fill your entire screen.  Move the children to wherever you want.  The RelativeLayout will still accept touch events, but the wont' be "consumed" and they'll pass to the Views behind.

Comment: Only got to testing it today - it does not seem to work - are you sure this "consuming" also works for my App in front of another app? Because as far as I can see, my App always returns false, but I can not press anything "behind" my app.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I remember doing this before, but I did it differently than I remembered.  I had to ensure that the overlay View was the size of the clickable portion of the screen, so there wasn't a container covering anything.  It sounds like you're trying to implement something similar this so it may be a good place to start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads