# How to implement Floating type MediaPlayer similar to Samsung Tab10.0

Tags: android, widget, media-player, popupwindow, viewdraghelper

I am working on a project where i want to implement mediaplayer as docked/Floating type similar to Gallary mediaPlayer of Samsung.

i was thinking of the following views/widgets but could not decide which would be helpful:

1. popupwindow
2. Android widget.
3. viewDragghelper.

Please suggest what to be used so that player continues to play even when we exits the application.

Here i attach a snapshot  for reference.

[image]

Comment: You can use [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html). TextureView can be moved, transformed, animated, etc. For instance, you can make a TextureView semi-translucent by calling myView.setAlpha(0.5f). Its for api level 14 and above. Not sure how you can make it work outside the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something that can **persists playing after you leave your main activity**, than you need to create your `View` hierarchy and attach it to a `Window` (like chat-heads does), using a `Service` as context.

You can find a working example **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)**.