# swipe gesture! android in lazy swipe app

Tags: android, user-interface

the lazy swipe app opens when user swipes from bottom left corner of the screen diagonally. how is this done? how lazy swipe app is only seen as an arc, and not on the whole screen? I want to make an app like that? please tell me how should I start to make that kind of swipe gesture?

Comment: Did you get any way to work around or a solution or an approach to start with? If so, please share it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I donw know the app, but there are serval ways to do that.
basically you have to override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and `onTouchEvent()` for your `View`

or

you can override `Activity.onTouchEvent()` to let the activity intercept all touch events.

Have a look here:
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

**Update:**
After reviewing [LazySwipe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lazyswipe): Lazy Swipe is using the same mechanism / android api as Facebook chats heads. It's not an activity. Basically its a `Service`. Here is a [discussion and implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads). There are also libraries on [Github](https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingView) (I have never used that one).

But as you see it's not an Activiy, hence you can not use `Activity.onTouch()`. However, you can display and interact any regular `View` or `ViewGroup`. Therefore, overriding `ViewGoroup.onInterceptTouchEvent()` and `ViewGorup.onTouchEvent()` is possible. So yes, you can detect Swipe gestures. 
There are alredy some gesture detectors build in on Android that you can use. Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html

Comment: will I be able to detect the swipe gesture from the home screen?