# Show icon while app is in background. Android

Tags: android, background, popup, icons

My goal is to create an application that even if it is in background.
to be more clear I show you some examples of what I would get. Is it possible to do.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add view using window manager addView method like the way facebook chathead has been implemented.
Please refer to link :[what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)

Comment: The problem is that with this system I can't see my image inside other applications like games.

Comment: use flag TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT for your layout param. And dont forget to add permission : android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW in manifest.

Comment: You solved my problem man. Last thing. How can Interact with my little icon. For example add an Clickeventlistener to it

Comment: You can setOnClickListener to the view you have added through window manager.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

**floatingBubble.java**

```
package com.likith.floatingbubble;

import com.likith.gesturelauncherPro.R;
import com.likith.gesturelauncherPro.gestureDrawer;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class FloatingFaceBubbleService extends Service 
{
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView floatingFaceBubble;

    @SuppressLint("RtlHardcoded")
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();
        floatingFaceBubble = new ImageView(this);
        floatingFaceBubble.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
        windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        final LayoutParams myParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        myParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        myParams.x=this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        myParams.y=0;
        windowManager.addView(floatingFaceBubble, myParams);

        try
        {
            floatingFaceBubble.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
            {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsT = myParams;
                private int initialX;
                private int initialY;
                private float initialTouchX;
                private float initialTouchY;
                private long touchStartTime = 0;
                @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                {
                    if(System.currentTimeMillis()-touchStartTime>ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() && initialTouchX== event.getX())
                    {
                        windowManager.removeView(floatingFaceBubble);
                        stopSelf();
                        return false;

                    }

                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {                    
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            touchStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            initialX = myParams.x;
                            initialY = myParams.y;
                            initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                            initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            myParams.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                            myParams.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                            windowManager.updateViewLayout(v, myParams);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            floatingFaceBubble.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent myNewActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),gestureDrawer.class);
                    myNewActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(myNewActivity);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

**LittleIcon.java**

```
package com.likith.floatingbubble;

import com.likith.gesturelauncherPro.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LittleIcon extends View
{
    private float viewX;
    private float viewY;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Bitmap androidIcon;

    public LittleIcon(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        androidIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas cvs) 
    {
        cvs.drawBitmap(androidIcon, viewX - androidIcon.getWidth() / 2, viewY - androidIcon.getHeight() / 2, mPaint);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        boolean touchedX = Math.abs(viewX - event.getX()) > androidIcon.getWidth();
        boolean touchedY = Math.abs(viewY - event.getY()) > androidIcon.getHeight();
        boolean isValidTouch = !touchedX && !touchedY;
        if (isValidTouch)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE|| event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
            {
                viewX = event.getX();
                viewY = event.getY();
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;

        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

**permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<service android:name="com.likith.floatingbubble.FloatingFaceBubbleService" />
```

**Usage**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(mainActivity.this, com.likith.floatingbubble.FloatingFaceBubbleService.class);
startService(intent);
```

Comment: Does this work also when other applications are opened?