# Running a layout in foreground

Tags: android, android-service, foreground

Can I run a relative or linear layout in the foreground of the device handling by swiping gestures? I have this code for foreground services but it only has a notification as an example and I haven't found something online that uses a layout. The code is below:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Depending on what you need, here's a question dealing with how Facebook implemented chat heads.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is just create Activity with transparent window. A good example is given here: [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

So when it starts it appears above every application and you can implement every layout you want.