# How to keep the image on the screen while browsing through other applications

Tags: android, overlay, translucency

I am making application to create an image on the screen and the app on my phone and still use the phone function normally. I guess to use
Overlay and  Activity translucent but I can not use the phone function.  I was wrong or am I missing something ? Can anyone help me please ?
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a  "facebook-chat-head" like icon on top of all application. right?

then its here,

> Allows an application to open windows using the type
>   TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, shown on top of all other applications. Very few
>   applications should use this permission; these windows are intended
>   for system-level interaction with the user.
>
> Constant Value: "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)

sample code:

```
public class ChatHeadService extends Service {

  private WindowManager windowManager;
  private ImageView chatHead;

  @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Not used
    return null;
  }

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_head);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
  }
}
```

> Don't forget to start the service somehow:

```
startService(new Intent(context, ChatHeadService.class));
```

The full code [here](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/):

please have a look at this thread: [chat head related techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)

Comment: Thank you for your answer so much,
but I want to set full image like wallpaper fullscreen

Comment: mark as accept if it helps, it will help others reaching out this question to get know it is working or nt.

Comment: My original intention was to do a wallpaper on the screen and is situated on applications like theme . I apologize for this misunderstanding