# Android Development: How to realize this? Moving Buttons and Gravity

Tags: android, gravity

I am developing an app and I would appreciate to get some input and your 2cents about this scenario:

I want to have 5 buttons in a circle and 1 button in the middle.

The buttons in the circle shall be able to be moved to the middle button and there are two scenarios:

if the button touches the middle button --> switch screen

if the button does not touch the middle button and you stop moving --> it should be moved back to the original place (gravity)

Is it optimal to solve this scenario with buttons or would you prefer any other item?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It really does not matter. Use Button if you like it or maybe an ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Developing this will take a lot of time and effort. I don't know if this can be done using simple buttons or you need custom elements but I can help you get started. Try looking into the Facebook chat heads behaviour. I think the behavior of chat heads when removing them (with the X circle in middle bottom where you drag chat heads to remove) is similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Here is some useful information you can go through and maybe you find what you're looking for.

[What APIs in Android is Facebook using to create Chat Heads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)

https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead

https://github.com/marshallino16/Demo-FloatingView

Note: I am still going through all the information in these links because it looks like it might be helpful for you. You also go through the links and we can further discuss  in the comments and later edit the answer when we have a solution

Comment: Wow, that's a great practical example! it's very close to the case!

Comment: I will review it and share my results - Thanks!