# How to pop a bubble on other android apps?

Tags: android, android-animation

When you are playing an app,time to alarm!If show a activity to remind you,it will disturb you!So,how to pop a bubble on other apps to remind you？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom notification with builder or you can create view For chat head like bubble view you can use facebook like chat head [Here is one sample for this chat head](https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead) you have to modify the working functions as per your requirement. or there is one nice solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15980900/3514144)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Notification that will live in the status bar until you click on it or swipe it away to dismiss.

Comment: I don not want to use "Notification",if the apps you are playing is full screen,you can not see the "Notification",so I think pop a bubble is good!

Comment: @Lollipop if you set the Notification priority to HIGH or MAX it is instead shown as a [Heads-up Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up).