# How I can minimize my application screen?

Tags: android-studio, screen

[image]

I want that when I exit my application, I want to minimize to square or circle like Facebook Messenger. I's that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I attached a screenshot of Messenger icon and like that i want to make my application when I exit my application without close it.

Comment: looks like they are called "chatheads", and here is a relevant post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads