# App that shows a popupwindow of the text user copies anywhere on his mobile

Tags: android

I want to make an app that shows a popupwindow of the text user copies anywhere on his mobile.i have less idea about how to run such a task.please if anyone can direct me the way.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A clever use of SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW could achieve what you are looking for.

> Allows an application to open windows using the type
>   TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, shown on top of all other applications. Very few
>   applications should use this permission; these windows are intended
>   for system-level interaction with the user.
>
> Constant Value: "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"

After creating a Service that handles the creation and data population of your popup view, you call it like this:

```
startService(new Intent(context, MyCustomService.class));
```

More information can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads).