# Implement Floating View for video streaming

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I want to implement `FloatingView`. Which make Activity resize and draggable (like following Picture). I also see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads) and based on that I create my own `service`. (Also See [this](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/springy-heads) & [this](https://github.com/recruit-lifestyle/FloatingView) libraries)

The problem is According to implementation I can't continue Video and Also sometimes Screen goes to black and nothing displayed. I want to know what is the correct way to handle this? Without Video interrupted and continue playing. (I know interruption because of `setOnPrepareListener` but how avoid that?)

Here is my code:

```
public class FloatingStream extends Service implements FloatingViewListener {


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (mFloatingViewManager != null) {
            return START_STICKY;
        }


        final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        floatingServiceBinder = new FloatingServiceBinder(this);
        final View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.view_exoplayer, null, false);
        final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(MY_URL));
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared() {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });

        mFloatingViewManager = new FloatingViewManager(this, this);
        mFloatingViewManager.setFixedTrashIconImage(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled);
        mFloatingViewManager.setActionTrashIconImage(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        final FloatingViewManager.Options options = new FloatingViewManager.Options();
        mFloatingViewManager.addViewToWindow(rootView, options);


        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

}
```

[image]

**Edit:** it's not [draggable panel](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel) because in this app if user go to another activity video not interrupted and still playing.

Comment: Hi, sorry for this dummy question, but when you say that you "can't continue video" what it means exactly? Is that you can't watch the video "smoothly"?

Comment: @jos As you see in Gif image video not stopped (or interrupted). when resize activity not need to call **setOnPreparedListener**.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve is [Picture in Picture](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/picture-in-picture.html), similar to what the YouTube app does.

Android officially supports this for TV, since Android N. For mobile devices however, you can use the [Draggable Panel library](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel).

Comment: Thanks But Draggable panel not work because it's bind to it's activity and when you go to another activity draggable destroyed.

Comment: That is why we use Fragments, my friend :)

Comment: Here is a link of application you think it's fragment ? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.perception.android.aio

Comment: That would be hard to tell. But if I were you, I'd use Fragments to get it done. I'm sure the library's README has sufficiently explained how to set it up.

Comment: I decompile APK I'm sure it's a service ;)

Comment: If you look at the library, the Draggable component is simply a View. You could either let the player reside in that View, or use a Fragment. Depends upon your usage.

Comment: Yeah I see this library. But how go to another activity without call setOnPreparedListener?