# Draw small activity over currently running app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been trying to figure out how to draw an activity over the current running app. My app consists of a service running in the background. It will wait till a certain apps opens and then it needs to draw the alert over the current running app. Someone told me about a floating activity but I can't get too much information on that. 
[This is what I want to archieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PbS6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest you take a look of this offical documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

I don't think you would be relying on an activity to achieve this "floating" result similar to the Facebook chat head.

This is a answer that you should see although it's working with pure Java.

[What APIs in Android is Facebook using to create Chat Heads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)

This code is written in Java, the partial translation is shown below. thanks @Cheesebaron

```
var windowManager = GetSystemService(WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();

var waitingImage = new ImageView (this);
waitingImage.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.Icon);
var param = new WindowManagerLayoutParams (
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                WindowManagerTypes.Phone,
                WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen,
                Format.Translucent);
param.Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;
waitingImage.SetScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.FitXy);

windowManager.AddView (waitingImage, param);
```