# Android push notification like facebook chatHead

Tags: android, facebook, push-notification, android-notifications

How to make notifications like facebook chatHead android .I tried various ways but nothing will happen . I want similar flow when new notification comes as in facebook chat Head.

Answer (score 0):

[Developer notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) you need to build notifaction

Answer (score 0):

How to create chat head:
[What APIs in Android is Facebook using to create Chat Heads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)

How to Get Started With Push Notifications: 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-get-started-with-push-notifications-on-android--cms-25870