# What WindowManager flag is Facebook Messenger chatheads using

Tags: android, overlay, facebook-messenger, android-windowmanager

I'm making an overlay by adding views directly to the window using `WindowManager`. However, I can't seem to find flags necessary to do what chathead does, which is to have the overlay **on top of the soft keyboard**. My overlay always gets covered by keyboard when it pops up.

this is the params I am using for my views that are added to the window

```
private WindowManager.LayoutParams touchableParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads

Comment: yea, i tried `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` but it does not go over the soft keyboard. AFAIK, the only difference between `TYPE_PHONE` and `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` is that the former is for all users and the latter is for the owning user

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your other requirements. I have been using this setup under Android 7.1.12 on a Google Pixel to make the overlay show **on top of the soft keyboard**. Hopefully this is what your are looking for.

```
mWindowsParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            width,
            height,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```