# How to get an image on top of other apps and homescreen like 'broken screen' apps

Tags: java, android, service, android-view

I've been reading all posts I could find about this topic but I could not find the answer I'm looking for.

There's a lot of apps with 'pranks' that show bugs running over your screen or cracks in your screen. These are seen on top of everything: homescreens other apps etc.

I've found methods with a service adding a view, but these require permissions. 
The apps I'm talking about don't require any permissions or just one for image acces.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

**Examples of Apps**

[Cracked Screen app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mk.g6.crackyourscreen)

[Ants on screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.just4fun.antsonscreen)

Comment: All of those apps, even those linked by you, ask for permission to draw over other apps. The SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission is automatically granted until L. Since M it must be explicitly enabled by the user in the system settings.

Comment: Ahh I see, the permission window didnt pop up for me when installing but this explains it. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [WindowsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html). 
You can see an example of window [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have a better look at the WindowsManager, but the example you gave still uses a permission. I don't understand how these apps can do it without one.