# How can I create an object in the android menu with Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Okay so messanger does it, I have seen plenty of other apps doing it as well, I'd like kind of create like a tomagachi, but more extreme/aggressive version of it as a game on the menu, with some twists, I am capable of doing that, have worked on numerous Android projects, but I never tried displaying something without a game window as you might say and this won't be that really effective and good without me being able to learn how to possible create an object [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX7NV.jpg). Thank you.

Comment: That looks like [What APIs in Android is Facebook using to create Chat Heads?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15975988/). Further searching with similar terms should provide addition resources. All of the resources I've seen show Java Android framework code so I'm not sure if your game character can be rendered in Unity .

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the reply, my fault for not being able to find it and making you answer, thanks.