# Draw over single application

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I have opened `"Google Map"` Application from my App.
What I want is I want to add my app button for navigating to my app,  over only google map not on other apps.

Using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads) ,I have added overlayservice to my app but it will overdraw over every other application on device window.

I only want to draw over google map app Like this.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

This started off as a comment, and then morphed into something of an answer.  One option would be to draw a custom marker on your Google Map for the taxi icon.  Whenever there is a zoom, drag, etc., you might have to do a re-render to get it in the same place again.  I can verify that it is possible to capture click events on a custom marker in Android.  Here is what your setup might look like:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(this);
    // ...
}
```

Then, override the marker click listener:

```
@Override
public void onCameraMove() {
    // remove the old marker, and redraw it again on the left of the screen
}
```

You also probably would want to capture click events on your custom marker:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    // ...
}
```

The above `onMarkerClick()` method receives a reference to the marker which was clicked.  You may keep an activity-scoped marker, and then check if it matches what was clicked to decide whether or not your custom marker were clicked.

Comment: As an aside to OP, if you make the link a deeplink it will be able to direct users to specific locations inside your app.