# How To Display A Floating Icon In Home Screen

Tags: java, android

I am building a lock screen app. I want to place a floating icon on Homescreen, which when clicked will lock the phone. I was able to implement the functionality of Locking the Phone using Device Manager API. Now I want to add a Floating Icon on Homescreen.

I tried using the solution recommended here:
[What APIs are used to draw over other apps (like Facebook's Chat Heads)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-are-used-to-draw-over-other-apps-like-facebooks-chat-heads)

But this does not seem to be working in my case. It is not diplaying an icon on the homescreen ever after gaining SYSTEM OVERLAY Permission.

**LockButtonService.java**

```
public class LockButtonService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;

    @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
    }

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        chatHead = new ImageView(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.lock);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
add_homescreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Code For Adding Shortcut Icon On Home Screen
//                if (ShortcutManagerCompat.isRequestPinShortcutSupported(getApplicationContext())) {
//                    ShortcutInfoCompat shortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "#1")
//                            .setIntent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockActivity.class).setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) // !!! intent's action must be set on oreo
//                            .setShortLabel("Lock Screen")
//                            .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.lock))
//                            .build();
//                    ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(getApplicationContext(), shortcutInfo, null);
//                } else {
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"launcher does not support short cut icon",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                }

                    //Code For Requesting System Overlay


                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext())) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 12345);
                    }
                    else {
                        //Code To Execute If The Permission Is Granted
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                       startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockButtonService.class));
                    }
                }




            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. It seems like I forgot to declare this service in Android Manifest. I was using WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE in LockButtonService.java.

I have now changed it into WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, and my icon is displaying on homescreen and all other activities.